# Computing data with fixed point representation and N decimal places

Tags: python, decimal, fixed-point

I'm trying to do some calculus with fixed point numbers while keeping a certain decimal precision (understood as the number of digits after the decimal point). Say I want to keep two digits after the decimal point.

I need to do some calculus like

```
10.00 + 0.01
```

and get

```
10.01
```

as answer. But then I want to add 100 and get `110.01` as answer.

So far, I managed to try the [`decimal` library](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html):

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

a = Decimal( '10.0000')
b = Decimal(  '0.0100')
c = Decimal('100.0000')

getcontext().prec=4
a+b    # results in Decimal('10.01')
a+b+c  # results in Decimal('110.0') <- Missing a decimal digit

getcontext().prec=5
a+b    # results in Decimal('10.010') <- Have one extra decimal digit
a+b+c  # results in Decimal('110.01')
```

So far, I only managed to control the number of total significant digits, but not the number of decimals after the decimal point.

So the question is: Is there any way to give freedom to the number of significant digits but restrain the number of digits after the decimal point?

Comment: The `quantize()` method seems relevant, though it doesn't seem possible to have quantizing to two decimal places be set as part of the context. You could always create your own class based on decimal which overrides the basic arithmetic operations so that the results are automatically quantized.

Comment: It is what I'm looking at right now. But having to subclass the whole class just to add this quirk that is commonly available (like width and precision in C) seems to be too much. I though I was missing something, didn't expected this would be so "hard".

Comment: Width and precision are not available in C if by that you mean something which creates [fixed-point arithmetic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). C uses double-precision floats just like Python. Width and precision are only for *printing* the results, and Python has the same ability to format how floats print. If fixed point arithmetic numbers in the sense of that Wikipedia article is what you want, it is somewhat surprising that there is no standard way to do it. Finding a way to use [Libfixmath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libfixmath) in Python could be nice.

Comment: Errr... touchê! I mixed both concepts for a second. I'm looking for the calculus side, not the representation. And you are completely right that C does not perform fixed point calculus, only representation. I'm doing some calculus with currencies, and them must be in fixed point, otherwise I'm getting some errors due to rounding :-/

Comment: One way to do currency is to just use integers. In effect, do all of your calculations in pennies. It does seem interesting. Looking a bit more, libfixmath isn't useful since that does *binary* fixed point but you want *decimal* fixed point. It probably wouldn't be a heavily used library, but a Python library which allows programmers to use various types of fixed point numbers would be nice.

Comment: Hummm... nos so easy, I will have to do some transformations. Some currencies use 2 decimals, others 6, others 8... it would be a nightmare to keep track of the proper precision of each integer. At the end, you need to develop a new class that encapsulates all of this, so it is easier to just stick on extending the `Decimal` class.